# React-Router display empty component when run in production

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've a problem with React-router-dom.

First. I have redux provider wrap the App component.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <AppContainer>
      <App/>
    </AppContainer>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

In **App** component, I have a **Navigation** component and a router.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navigation from './components/navigationComponent/navigation.component';
import Home from './components/homeComponent/home.component';

export class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Navigation />
        <Router>
          <Route exact path="/" component={ Home }/>
        </Router>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

It's worked and show when a run on webpack-dev-server. But the production version is not good. The **Navigation** is showed but all component in Router is not displayed and have a comment *react-empty*.

How can i resolve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Try and change the naming convention `navigation.component` to something like `navigation_component`

Comment: Is your production url "/"? Might be obvious but who knows :)

Comment: import {Switch } from 'react-router-dom';<Switch> <Route exact path="/" component ={Home} > try Switch above the Route.

Comment: thanks @Andrija about your answer. I've tried to upload my site on hosting. The path is correct and router is working now. Thanks